# Ftp: Why does !cd not work?

Tags: unix, command-line, ftp

When connected to an ftp server, using cd, pwd, ls etc navigates the remote server.
For the local server there are some special commands, like lcd, lpwd etc, as well as the ! command.

While !ls and !pwd work, why does !cd .. not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "not work" needs to be defined in the original problem statement.

While in `ftp` you can do:

```
`!cd foo`
```

And it will not produce an error if `foo` is a local folder. However, when using `!` from `ftp` (or usually from any command that supports "escaping" commands to the shell in this manner, such as `vi`), each instance of `!` usage is its own sub-shell. Therefore, when the command completes, the action taken by `cd` is no longer in effect and you're back where you were. So:

```
ftp> !pwd
/home/mortimer
ftp> !ls
doc misc
ftp> !cd doc
ftp> !ls
doc misc
```

`cd` appears "not to work" but it actually did work. It's just that when your shell instance from `!` completed, the effect of `cd` is no longer there (each instance of the shell maintains its own working directory state).

Try it this way to illustrate:

```
ftp> !ls
doc misc
ftp> !ls doc
foo.txt bah.txt
ftp> !cd doc ; ls
foo.txt bah.txt
ftp> !ls
doc misc
```

So here, the `cd` worked as shown by the `ls` command that was executed in the *same instance of the shell*.

This is why `ftp` provides unique commands to change the local directory (`lcd`). The `lcd` command is not executed in a sub-shell by `ftp`, but rather actually changes the current working directory that it's operating in:

```
ftp> !ls
doc misc
ftp> lcd doc
Local directory now /home/mortimer/doc
ftp> !ls
foo.txt bah.txt
```

(The above is run with the BSD `ftp` program that shows the "Local directory..." message when `lcd` is executed.)

Answer (score 0):

`!` is used to run shell commands. The command is run in a subshell.

`cd` command in a subshell is only valid for the subshell; it does not affect the parent process.